# C++ Cross Platform Timeout reads

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, boost-asio

I am implementing a test server for bots competing in an [AI competition](http://theaigames.com/competitions/conquest), the bots communicate with the server via standard input/output. The bots only have so long for their turns. In a previous AI competition I wrote the server in [Java](https://github.com/grom358/pokeraichallenge/blob/master/src/pokeraichallenge/BotConnection.java) and handled this by using BlockingQueue and threads on the blocking reads/write to the process streams.

For this competition looking to use C++. I found [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.async_io) and Boost.Asio but as far as I can tell, Asio library doesn't have a way to timeout on how long to wait for a read. It has been designed around using callback functions to tell you when the read has completed. Whereas I want to block but with a maximum timeout. I could do this with platform specific API like select but looking for more cross platform solution. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** To clarify I want a class BotConnection that deals with communicating with the bot process that has two methods eg: string readLine(long timeoutInMilliseconds) and void writeLine(string line, long timeoutInMilliseconds) . So the calling code is written like it is using a blocking call but can timeout (throwing an exception or change the method signatures above so a successful flag is returned on if the operation completed or timedout)

Comment: Another idea I had was to use C++11 threads around the input/outstream from Boost.Process like in the java solution.

Comment: ‘select‘ and ‘poll‘ provide io waits with optional timeouts

Comment: Which platforms? If all unix, `select` is probably the most portable. If you need windows in the mix, I'm not sure.

Comment: mostly windows and linux platforms I want to support. IIRC windows select is only for sockets.

Comment: Just found this, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp which on first look seems to have timeout blocking read/writes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create timer objects that track the timeout. A typical approach is to create a regular timer with an async handler. Each time it fires you iterate over your connection objects looking for those which have not transmitted any data. In your connection read handlers you flag the object as having received data. In rough pseudo-code:

```
timer_handler:
  for cnx in connections:
    if cnx.recv_count > 0:
      cnx.recv_count = 0
      cnx.idle_count = 0
      continue

    cnx.idle_count += 1
    if cnx.idle_count > idle_limit:
      cnx.close()


cnx_read_handler:
  cnx.recv_count += 1
```

Note: I've not used asio, but I did check and timer's do appear to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to read and write to standard input and output with a timeout.

- Boost.Asio provides [`posix::stream_descriptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html) to synchronously and asynchronously read and write to POSIX file descriptors, such as standard input and output, as demonstrated in the [posix chat client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp).  While Boost.Asio does not provide support for cancelling synchronous operations, most asynchronous operations can be cancelled in a portable way.  Asynchronous operations combined with Boost.Asio Timers allow for timeouts: an asynchronous operation is initiated on an entity, a timer is set and if the timer expires then `cancel()` is invoked on the entity.  See the Boost.Asio [timeout examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.timeouts) for more details.
- Windows standard handles do not support asynchronous I/O via completion ports.  Hence, Boost.Asio's [`windows::stream_handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html)'s documentation notes that named pipes are supported, but anonymous pipes and console streams are not.  There are a few unanswered questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19037552/1053968) one, about asynchronous I/O support for standard input and output handles.  With the lack of asynchronous support, additional threads and buffering may be required to abstract the platform specific behavior from the application.

Comment: Yeah I had seen that part about deadline timers, but I still don't get how I can combine that to hide all these details in the BotConnection class. That is wait/block until either the operation completes or the deadline timer expired.