# Excel VBA hangs up when communicating with external process through StdIn and StdOut

Tags: vba, excel

I've create a simple ProgramExecutor class in VBA to facilitate communication with console application.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wshShell, shellExec

Public Sub Run(dir As String, executable As String)
    Set wshShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshShell.CurrentDirectory = dir
    Set shellExec = wshShell.exec(executable)
End Sub

Public Sub SendCommand(command As String)
     oExec.StdIn.WriteLine command
End Sub

Public Function GetResponse() As String
        Dim sOutput As String
        While Not shellExec.stdOut.AtEndOfStream
            sOutput = sOutput & shellExec.stdOut.ReadLine
            If Not shellExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream Then
               shellExec.StdErr.ReadLine
            End If
        Wend
        GetResponse = sOutput
End Function

Public Sub Terminate()
    shellExec.Terminate
End Sub
```

I've tried to communicate with simple application but every time I invoke `shellExec.stdOut.AtEndOfStream` or `shellExec.stdOut.readAll` when application expecting input the macro hangs up.

Application code looks as follows

```
namespace SampleChat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var text = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Echo {text}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I read the whole stdOut when application expecting something on stdIn after writing text to stdOut?

Sample usage:

```
Public Sub StartChatting()
    Dim executor As ProgramExecutor
    Set executor = New ProgramExecutor
    executor.Run "C:\Projects\SampleChat\SampleChat\bin\Debug", "samplechat.exe"
    Dim messageToSend As String, sOutput As String

    Do While True
        messageToSend = InputBox("Type message")
        If messageToSend = vbNullString Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        executor.SendCommand messageToSend
        sOutput = executor.GetResponse()
        MsgBox (sOutput)
    Loop
    executor.Terminate
End Sub
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking ... you appear to have it backward about your application `application expecting something on stdIn after writing text to stdOut`  .... your application is expecting something on stdin `before` writing text to stdout

Comment: @jsotola I would like to read whole data from stdOut in VBA even if application is expecting something on stdIn after writing text to stdOut. I need to achieve two-way communication through stdOut and stdIn between VBA and external app.

Comment: here is some non-blocking code that may work.  way at bottom posted by Mark Fisher. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294954/non-blocking-read-of-stdin#11320885

Comment: the other way would be to use a "heartbeat" signal. have the application send out something (maybe a null .. &h00) at an interval when there is no data to send.